# Duplicate records are being inserted into database

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out, why there are sometimes being inserted duplicate products into database. I just don't seem to find it. Here follows the code.

This is how the dump of session for storing products data looks:

```
array (size=5)
  'totalcount' => int 8
  'totalprice' => int 11592
  '54e22beb92d83' => 
    array (size=7)
      'pieces' => string '1' (length=1)
      'id' => string '41' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Chardonnay 2009' (length=15)
      'specs_price' => int 0
      'price' => int 599
      'total' => int 599
      'code' => string '' (length=0)
  '54e22bf562387' => 
    array (size=7)
      'pieces' => string '2' (length=1)
      'id' => string '42' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Chardonnay 2010' (length=15)
      'specs_price' => int 0
      'price' => int 499
      'total' => int 998
      'code' => string '' (length=0)
  '54e22bf79c386' => 
    array (size=7)
      'pieces' => string '5' (length=1)
      'id' => string '43' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Chardonnay 1993' (length=15)
      'specs_price' => int 0
      'price' => int 1999
      'total' => int 9995
      'code' => string '' (length=0)
```

I think this is pretty self-explanatory, but just to be sure, the array is made of totalcount, totalprice, sale_code (if present) and the other keys are products in basket.

Here is the code at end of order process that saves the data to database:

```
foreach ($_SESSION[self::BASKET_IDENTIFIER] as $key => $values) {
    if ($key != 'totalcount' && $key != 'totalprice' && $key != 'sale_code') {
        $spec = '';
        $speccost = 0;
        if (isset($values['spec']) && is_array($values['spec'])) {
            foreach ($values['spec'] as $id => $value) {
                $specname = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT `name` FROM `products_types_properties` WHERE `id`='$id'")->fetch_assoc()["name"];
                $spec .= "<br>$specname: $value";
            }
            foreach ($values['spec_cost'] as $id => $value) {
                $speccost += $value;
            }
        } else {
            $spec = null;
        }
        if (isset($values['voucher_price'])) {
            $voucher_price = "'$values[voucher_price]'";
        } else {
            $voucher_price = "NULL";
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO `orders_products`
                            (
                            `order_id`,
                            `product_id`,
                            `pieces`,
                            `spec`,
                            `spec_costs`,
                            `voucher_price`,
                            `price`
                            ) VALUES (
                            '$order_id',
                            '$values[id]',
                            '$values[pieces]',
                            '$spec',
                            '0',
                            $voucher_price,
                            '$values[price]'
                            )";
        $this->mysqli->query($query);
        if ($this->mysqli->error) {
            echo $this->mysqli->error;
            exit;
        }
    }
    }
```

What is really strange, that the same order gets processed well in PDF file that is sent to email, but from the same data it somehow inserts bad records into database.

This is the code for generating PDF:

```
protected function PDF($ordernum) {
    $basket = new Basket();
    $basket->recount();
    $delivery = new Delivery($this->delivery);
    $pdf = new mPDF("utf8");
    $country = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT `name` FROM `countries` WHERE `id`='$this->country'")->fetch_assoc()["name"];
    $css = file_get_contents(PATH . "/config/pdf_template/template.css");
    $html = file_get_contents(PATH . "/config/pdf_template/template.html");
    $html = str_replace("{{cislo_objednavky}}", $ordernum, $html);
    $html = str_replace("{{jmeno_prijmeni}}", "$this->name $this->surname", $html);
    $html = str_replace("{{ulice}}", $this->street, $html);
    $html = str_replace("{{psc}}", $this->zip, $html);
    $html = str_replace("{{mesto}}", $this->city, $html);
    $html = str_replace("{{stat}}", $country, $html);
    $html = str_replace("{{doprava}}", getCzechPriceFormat($this->delivery_price[$this->delivery]), $html);
    $html = str_replace("{{nazev_dopravy}}", $delivery->getTitle(), $html);
    $totalprice = $basket->totalprice + $this->delivery_price[$this->delivery];
    if ($totalprice < 0) {
        $totalprice = 0;
    }
    $html = str_replace("{{celkem}}", getCzechPriceFormat($totalprice), $html);

    $parts = "";
    $parts .= "<table width='100%'>";
    $parts .= "<tr>";
    $parts .= "<th>Název</th>";
    $parts .= "<th>Počet ks</th>";
    $parts .= "<th>Cena za kus</th>";
    $parts .= "<th>Celkem</th>";
    $parts .= "</tr>";
    foreach ($_SESSION[self::BASKET_IDENTIFIER] as $key => $values) {
        if (!in_array($key, Basket::$banned_slugs)) {
            $spec = '';
            if (is_array($values['spec'])) {
                foreach ($values['spec'] as $id => $value) {
                    $specname = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT `name` FROM `products_types_properties` WHERE `id`='$id'")->fetch_assoc()["name"];
                    $spec .= "<br>$specname: $value";
                }
            } else {
                $spec = null;
            }
            $part = "";
            $part .= "<tr>";
            $part .= "<td><strong>$values[name]</strong>$spec</td>";
            $part .= "<td>$values[pieces]</td>";
            $part .= "<td>" . getCzechPriceFormat($values['price']) . "</td>";
            $part .= "<td>" . getCzechPriceFormat($values['total']) . "</td>";
            $part .= "</tr>";
            $parts .= $part;
        }
    }
    $parts .= "</table>";

    $html = str_replace("{{products}}", $parts, $html);
//      var_dump($html);exit;

    $pdf->WriteHTML($css, 1);
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $pdf->Output(PATH . "/pdf/orders/$ordernum.pdf");
}
```

Can someone please help me figure it out? I really can't find why, which is a shame, because I wrote the whole system. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you set `unique` constraints or a `primary key` in the database?

Comment: Yes, I can. I forgot to mention, that the ID is always unique (it's primary key and auto increment), just the data duplicates.